# iconv - retaining characters that cannot be converted to ascii

Tags: c, ascii, iconv, libiconv

I'm using iconv's transliterate function to convert a unicode string to the nearest ASCII equivalent. However, the string contains some symbols which do not have an ASCII equivalent. I want to retain such symbols without dropping them.

Currently, here's what I am doing:

```
iconv_t cd = iconv_open("ASCII//IGNORE//TRANSLIT", "UTF-8");
const char *utf8 = "ç ß ∑ a";

char* in = const_cast<char*>(utf8);
size_t in_bytes = strlen(in);

char buf[BUFSIZ] = {};
char* out = buf;
size_t out_bytes = sizeof(buf);

iconv(cd, &in, &in_bytes, &out, &out_bytes);

printf("%s", buf);

// prints 
c ss  a
```

How do I configure iconv to produce an output like the following:

```
c ss ∑
```

If this is not possible with iconv, is there a way to achieve this programatically otherwise?

Comment: From the doc: "The iconv function converts one multibyte character at a time"

Comment: That seems like such a weird thing to do though :D  What are you going to use this interesting function for?

Comment: Well, first of all the command you posted does not produce that output on my machine, but rather it errors out (maybe remove the `//IGNORE`?). Secondly, `iconv` is just a simple command line utility, in a C program you *should* be able to just try and translate each Unicode code-point by itself and see the result. What did you write that didn't work? You should add the relevant C code.

Comment: I've added the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

`iconv` does not support the conversion behaviour that you want to see out-of-the-box, because it is a quite odd behaviour: If it's OK to have a ∑ in the output, why would it not have OK to have a ß in the output?

Anyway, you can implement this conversion through a function of your own, that uses iconv, as follows:

1. Allocate two conversion descriptors:

   ```
   iconv_t cd0 = iconv_open("UTF-8", "UTF-8");
   iconv_t cd1 = iconv_open("ASCII//TRANSLIT", "UTF-8");
   ```
2. Use a loop that converts part of the string repeatedly, through iconv() with `cd1`. When the call fails with errno == EILSEQ, you know that it's because of a character that cannot be transliterated to ASCII.
3. At this point use an iconv() call with `cd0`, to convert one and only one character. You do this by calling iconv() with in = 1, then if that fails with in = 2, and so on up to in = 4. (If all of these fail, you must have invalid input; your best bet is to skip one input byte and leave a single '?' in output.)
4. After the no-op conversion of a single character, go back to step 2.